# lamp and laravel installation

Tags: 12.04, lamp, laravel

I just installed lamp via terminal and gave mysql password, I want to use the laravel framework, how do i install that and use it via lamp and then how do I start the apache server and mysql and get started with the development? I have only used windows before so thats why im asking, thanks.

Comment: Apache2 automatically start when you boot your computer. If it is not the case, you can launch it manually by doing `sudo service apache2-start`

Answer (score 1):

**Basic stuff install**

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

**LAMP**

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

**CURL + Composer**

```
sudo apt-get install curl php-curl php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-gettext
```

**enable mods**

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Install phpmyadmin**

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

later accessible through http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Creating Laravel Project

```
cd /var/www/html/

sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel app_name --prefer-dist
sudo chmod -R 777 app_folder_name
php artisan serve
```

and that's it...go to http://localhost:8000 and it's available there....

I have made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6TdaRIsG6g) with detailed instructions:

Answer (score 0):

(1) Composer

Laravel utilizes Composer to manage its dependencies. So, before using Laravel, make sure you have Composer installed on your machine.
[install composer here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)

(2) download the Laravel installer using Composer:

> composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.

(3)Via Composer Create-Project

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Now check your laravel 5 installation here: http://localhost:8000